# python turtle loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, turtle-graphics

I am trying to create a looping square, and cannot figure out how to get my code to allow me to keep repeating the command of creating squares, times the number input, heres what I have currently.

```
square_count = input("Enter the number of squares to draw: ")
count_int = int(square_ct)

if count_int > 1:

    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.end_fill()

    turtle.up()
    turtle.forward(20)
    turtle.color(random.random(),random.random(), random.random())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `for i in range(count_int):` to run a piece of code repeatedly given a repeat count in `count_int`:

```
if count_int > 1:
    for i in range(count_int):
        turtle.begin_fill()
        turtle.forward(100)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(100)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(100)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(100)
        turtle.end_fill()

        turtle.up()
        turtle.forward(20)
        turtle.color(random.random(),random.random(), random.random())
```

Comment: Is there a better way to write `turtle.forward(100)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(100)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(100)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(100)` as they are same values repeating multiple times?

Comment: @DebRaj: See [Python 3: Can we avoid repeating an instance name when calling several of its methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35407914), which is probably why you posted your comment in the first place.

Comment: @Martin Pieters The link is about a varied movement. I wanted it to be for a similar movement reputation. I found defining a method is helpful like : `def draw_square(some_draw): for i in range (0, 4): some_draw.forward(100) some_draw.right(90)` and then calling it as `draw_square(my_drawing_name)` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing this

```
x=1
while x < 10000000:
```

when you do this anything you type after this will be done again until it has been done 10000000 times.
at the end though you have to put this in.

```
x+=1
```

Heres am example i made.

```
import turtle
bob = turtle.Turtle()
wn = turtle.Screen()
bob.color("white")
bob.speed(1000000000000000000000000)
wn.bgcolor("black")
x=1
while x < 10000000:
bob.forward(90)
bob.left(89)
bob.forward(1+x)
```

Answer (score -1):

then again, you could just put it in a function and tell it to run itself again

```
def example():
    [insert code]
    example()
```

Comment: How would you suggest preventing this from executing infinitely?