# Python 3: Can we avoid repeating an instance name when calling several of its methods?

Tags: python, vba, attributes, instance-variables

I now (or so I have read) that it is not possible in Python 2.x, and can't find it for Python 3 either, but maybe I don't know how to search for it... 
It easier to explain it with a simple Python example:

```
for i in range(11):
    one_turtle.penup()
    one_turtle.forward(50)
    one_turtle.down()
    one_turtle.forward(8)
    one_turtle.up()
    one_turtle.forward(8)
    one_turtle.stamp()
    one_turtle.forward(-66)
    one_turtle.left(360/12)
```

I'd like to avoid repeating "one_turtle" the same way you can do in VBA, which it would result in something similar to this:

```
For i = 1 To 11
    With one_turtle.penup()
        .forward(50)
        .down()
        .forward(8)
        .up()
        .forward(8)
        .stamp()
        .forward(-66)
        .left(360/12)
```

The code resulting from the With keyword is much clearer and easy to write and read (it'll need an `End With` and a `Next` lines but I wanted to focus the discussion). One of the main reasons I have decided to learn Python is because it is said to be very neat and "zen-like" to program. Is it really not possible to do this?

Comment: The turtle module doesn't support method chaining, no; the methods simply return `None` instead of the `Turtle` instance. This isn't particularly a language-specific feature however; SQLAlchemy uses method chaining extensively.

Comment: As commented above, the functions do not allow chaining. If you are allowed to edit the Turtle code, just make forward, down, up, stamp etc. return self instead of whatever they're returning now.

Comment: @Martijn OH, so it depends on the module... Good that some of them have this, but on the other way, this adds more things to learn about each module. It complicates things if we can make have this sort of general behavior with some methods and not with others. Not sure if I would need to open another question for this but, is there any reason why this hasn't been implemented in Python 3.x as a general norm or is it just that we need someone to have the time to do it? - hard to believe that VBA makes this simpler... but good to know some modules allow it!

Comment: @Martec: you can't implement this as a general norm. Method chaining is an explicit API style choice, not a language design choice. And for built-in types the convention has been for methods that mutate object state in-place to return `None` (`list.append()`, `list.sort()`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters I guess there's a rationale behind that which BVA doesn't have to follow -and I think neither has Java-  and which I'd need to investigate further...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your definition of all these member-methods, simply return `self`.
eg. Change definition of `penup()` like this:

```
def penup(self):
    # Your logic
    return self
```

Comment: How exactly returning self help here to call .forward() ?

Comment: because this function returns self (your object instance) you can call whatever other function on the result. one_turtle.penup() returns one_turtle, so one_turtle.penup().forward() applies forward to that object again

Comment: +1 for the explanation by @WorkofArtiz. Alok, you can refer this small fiddle for reference: http://pythonfiddle.com/python-inline-builder-pattern/

Comment: Thanks. Just that the solution for the example I wrote is even more work demanding than simply repeating the object name as I'd need to modify the module I'm using and do it for every function/method I need to call... But it seems Python's methods (contrary to VBA?) need to always return something  (I'll learn more on this as it seems I need to) so the definitions should specify to return the object with 'self' and the only option we have by now when calling modules that don't do that is to modify the modules themselves... @WorkofArtiz

Comment: Yet it will work when defining our own functions, or if our code is long enough to make tinkering with other's code worthy. So I'm voting up even though it is not what I would have liked and expected for Python (there might be a reason for that that I still don't understandand but at least initially is burdensome). Thanks...

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to just have a simple keyword or symbol (like ".." for example) that behaves as a function returning the object specified in the previous statement so that we can do something as simple as in the second example of the question? Can this at least be done at IDE level (each time we start a statment with ".." it would replace it with the previous object name?

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution is I think already posted, returning `self` is simply the cleanest way. However if you're not able to edit the turtle object or whatever, you can create an alias:

```
forward = one_turtle.forward
... some code ...
forward()
```

Now the function forward just applies forward to one_turtle, simple example

```
s = "abc"
x = s.upper
print(x()) # prints "ABC"
```